# Compiler option for missing include file on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

It's been a while since I've dealt with C/C++, so forgive me if this is a ridiculously easy to answer question - I just don't quite know how to "Google" it.

I have a file, `"MyFile.h"` that includes file `"includedFile.h"`. However, the compiler cannot find the file. Please see below picture:

[image: File/folder structure for project foo.]

What I'm doing is moving the project from an old Solaris box to a Linux box. The weird thing is that it worked on the Solaris box as-is but Linux is a little confused.

The `makefile` that I use for the project hasn't changed either which makes me think that it may be a compiler option...

So how do I tell the compiler on Linux where that include file is, or how do I specify it in `"MyFile.h?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gcc and clang, you specify the include path using `-I`:

`g++ -o myprogram main.cc extra.cc -I/usr/include/boost -I/my/extra/include/files`

You *can* specify full paths *in* your files, as in `#include "/path/to/my/includedfile.h"`, but I strongly discourage this as it forces everyone who wants to compile your code to comply with that directory layout.

Also relevant: Read the following link for the difference between `#include <file>` and `#include "file"`  in gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Comment: What's clang - is it another c++ compiler?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed another compiler.

Comment: Very nice - thank you for the link! And I agree about the full-path in the file version: really didn't want to have to do that.

Comment: It should be noted that the `-I` option is probably one of the most generic of all compiler options, so you can pretty much take ANY compiler you like and use `-I someplace_where_my_headers_live` and get what you want - it's far from specific to `gcc` or `g++`.

Comment: it's just strange to me that the compiler for Solaris didn't require the -I option...Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using g++, you pass a path with the `-I` flag.

```
g++ ..... -I<a path to your includes> -I<another path to includes>
```